# Isolating a small pin on a flat cable

Tags: pcb, cables, isolation, ffc

A motor on my HiFi system (which is supposed to lift a volume controller) has broken. The motor is stuck and I don't want to fix the mechanical part. I assume disassembling the volume controller would cause problems.

However, I have access to the flat cable to the complete volume unit. I'd like to isolate the motor pin. The flat cable looks like this one:

[image: Image of flat cable]

([Image source - AliExpress](https://de.aliexpress.com/item/5-pcs-200MM-Length-30-Pin-0-5mm-Pitch-FFC-TTL-Ribbon-Flat-Cable-Reverse-Direction/32463355787.html))

The pins are really tiny. How could I isolate the pin? It would be great if this is reversible. I thought about using nail polish. This usually works well on bigger connectors. However I fear it might be too thick or be too hard to apply on only one pin. Are there other "more professional" approaches to make such on PCB changes?

Comment: Trace the PCB tracks with a magnifier lens.

Answer (score 2):

Kapton tape.  Cut a tiny piece up on a nonsticky backer (like taken from another adhesive product) and stick on.  Also used to isolate under one pin of a QFP (unsolder, bend up slightly, stick underneath).  Available at Uline and other fine online retailers.

Comment: if you have a laptop computer, then remove one of the panels on the underside .... you may find some Kapton tape holding a harness .... just cut a piece

Comment: Thank, that sounds quite professional. I don't have found a device yet which I could open. I'll keep looking and try it out.